# Basic transformation of a term

Tags: induction, binomial-theorem

I know this is a really basic question for most of you, but I just can't figure it out.

I am currently learning about induction in university and I have a question about the following:

$$
((n^3+3n^2+3n+1)-(n+1))\,\,mod\,\,3 = 0
$$
transforms into:
$$
((n^3-n)+(3n^2+3n))\,\,mod\,\,3 = 0
$$

Now I know that the first one is a binomial formula of $(n+1)^3$, but I can't figure out how to get from the first to the second line

Comment: It's just a result of grouping the terms differently after you take away $n+1$ from $n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1$. Just don't take $n$ from $3n$ and then bracket things accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, so simple yet i couldnt see it :)

Comment: No worries, glad I could help! Don't worry too much about missing simple stuff, we all do it :')

Comment: Exactly , every mistake or miss teaches you something , so never feel bad ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since multiplication is *distributive* over addition, for any real numbers $a$, $x$, and $y$ we have
$$
a(x+y)=ax+ay \, .
$$
For the special case $a=-1$,
$$
-(x+y)=-1(x+y)=-1x+(-1)y=-x-y \, .
$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
n^3+3n^2+3n+1-(n+1) &= n^3+3n^2+3n+1-n-1 \\
&= n^3+3n^2+2n
\end{align}
This is the same as $(n^3-n)+(3n^2+3n)$.